# SAS - INTNX Defining a Week

Tags: sas

I have been using a SAS code I have written to group a historical dataset (that gets updated weekly) by grouping them into weeks (Sunday - Saturday = 1 group).  I have been using INTNX.

Our definition of a week has now changed and is Tuesday through Monday.  How can I update the code below to make that adjustment.  I have been messing with the 'Week' function and trying to add days to the end to make this change but to no success.

Currently, I am using:

```
WEEKOF = INTNX('Week', SasDate,0);
```

Where "SasDate" is the date of each record in my dataset.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply change it to

```
weekof = intnx('week.3',sasdate,0,'beginning') ;
```

Sun = 1, Mon = 2, Tue = 3, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much - that worked like a charm.  I kept trying to -2 to the end of the statement or add to my 'sasdate' none of which worked like this - thanks!